# dev.azure.com throwing certificate error on Windows Server 2016

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup DevOps Pipelines self-hosted agent on Windows Server 2016 and connection to dev.azure.com is having error 12175. If I try to browse the URL in IE, I get:

`The security certificate presented by this website was not issued by a trusted certificate authority.`

CA is **Microsoft IT TLS CA 1**. No matter how I installed the CA in "Trusted Root CA" store under my account or local machine, IE will not recognize it and continue to throw error:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was resolved. "Baltimore CyberTrust Root" certificate was missing in one of the two Certificate Stores (certmgr.msc and certlm.msc). Please check both of them. Once installed, certificate issue disappeared. Baltimore is CA Root for Microsoft IT TLS CA certificates. That certificate is available for download [here](https://www.digicert.com/digicert-root-certificates.htm).

Comment: Much appreciate this solution shared here! You can accept your answer, so that others could directly know this is work.

Answer (score 1):

For issue about accessing the dev.azure.com website:

**Microsoft IT TLS CA 1 certificate** is used Azure Devops service Organization website (e.g. dev.azure.com/organization name).

This website (dev.azure.com) needs the **Microsoft IT TLS CA 2 certificate**. You could try to install this certificate.

Here are the [steps](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931850/there-is-a-problem-with-this-website-s-security-certificate-when-you-t):

1. In Windows Internet Explorer, click **Continue to this website (not recommended).**
2. Click the **Certificate Error** button to open the information window.
3. Click **View Certificates,** and then click **Install Certificate.**
4. On the warning message that appears, click **Yes** to install the certificate.

For agent settings:

You need to connect the agent to  specific organization URL (e.g. dev.azure.com/organization name).

Here is a doc about [the steps to create a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#server-url-and-authentication).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are right about certificate 1 and 2. Indeed, I'm trying to access dev.azure.com/<org> URL. Hence, it's CA 1. I found the cause and it is shared below.